# spring-webflux: Is it a good practice to subscribe a publisher manually from a method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, reactive

The sendRequestToSasAsync send request to external entity which takes time to respond and sometimes I need to retry the requests with backoff and jitter. So, I'm using spring-webflux Mono and creating a pipeline to call external entity and perform retries in case of errors.

The error specification I have defined in `requestRetrySpec`.

```
Void caller(...) {
   /**
   * Some logic
   */

   for (int i = 0; i < requests.size(); i++) {
      // subscribe to the publisher to trigger async requests
      sendRequestToSasAsync(requests.get(i), deviceInfo, grantMapEntries.get(i),
          provider).subscribe();
   }
}


Mono<Void> sendRequestToSasAsync(Frequency freq, DeviceInfo deviceInfo,
    Map<String, Grant> grantMapEntry, String provider) {
  return fromCallable(() -> sendRequestToSas(freq, deviceInfo, grantMapEntry, provider))
      .flatMap(result -> handleResponse(result, grantMapEntry, deviceInfo))
      .retryWhen(requestRetrySpec)
      .subscribeOn(elasticScheduler);
}
```

Q: As, you can see I'm subscribing `sendRequestToSasAsync` publisher from within the code as I need to trigger the flow. Is it a good practice to subscribe publishers from within the code and not from framework? Like in case of reactive REST APIs we don't need explicit subscription to the publisher.

Please help as only recently I started using webflux again. Thanks